# Derivative of a single point (not a point in a function, but a point).

Tags: calculus

I know that the derivative of a line is its slope, and that a constant is a line with slope zero, so the derivative is zero.

But how does it work if instead of a constant, or a line, you had a single point?  Is it just simply undefined?  I tried to google for something about this but it always just returns info on "how to find the derivative at a point in a function".  Which is far more useful but doesn't answer my curious question.

Let's assume you just have an X,Y graph and are given the point (5,10).  The definition of a derivative includes a function so I'm guessing it's just not defined but wanted some more expert input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find an answer to  your curious question because the question makes no sense. Derivatives were invented to study *change*. When your position changes over time the derivative is your velocity. When you climb a mountain and your height changes as you move horizontally the derivative is the slope. That's essentially the same slope you see in a graph when the value of $y$ changes as $x$ changes. There is no way to think about how an isolated point changes. On a particular mountain trail at a particular point there's a slope, but a point floating in the air has no slope.

Comment: Alright so I guess I was somewhat right in thinking it isn't defined.  Thank you.  I'll accept your answer when the time limit is up in 8 mins.